# AWS Amplify pod install dependency version error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I am trying to add AWS AppSync to my podfile and when I am trying to install the pod dependency with the `pod install` command it throws the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AWSCore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    AWSCore (= 2.12.1, ~> 2.12.0)

  In Podfile:
    AWSAppSync (~> 2.14.2) was resolved to 2.14.2, which depends on
      AWSCore (~> 2.10.2)

    AWSAuthUI (~> 2.12.0) was resolved to 2.12.1, which depends on
      AWSCore (= 2.12.1)

    AWSCore (~> 2.12.0)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to get the versions to match is one option but will lose any of the new features in the latest versions. The latest compatiable versions with each other should be up to date in the documentation. If it's not, then there is a bug in the documentation and please open a Github Issue with the documentation repo.

From https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/ios/start#step-1-configure-your-app

The current guidance is to use:

```
target :'YOUR-APP-NAME' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.12.0'
    pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 2.14.2'

    # other pods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing all the versions to 2.9.0 and AWSAppSync's version to 2.10.0 worked for me. Why it wouldn't work with the latest versions still bothers me. Would be really helpful if someone could explain. TIA